# Extjs 6 - Number of items per page

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid, store

I've applied the code on this link https://edspencer.net/2009/07/28/extjs-grid-page-size-letting-user/ and it's turned error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'doLoad'

So does anyone can explain me what happen and why this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the second part of the sample code, line 13, the code does refer to the function `doLoad` of the PagingToolbar, which [is a private function in ExtJS 4.0.7](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/Paging.html#Ext-toolbar-Paging-method-doLoad), and [does no longer exist as of 4.2.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Paging.html#Ext-toolbar-Paging-method-doLoad) already.

Private methods can be changed without notice, so the problem is with the code sample you are using, which is obviously hopelessly outdated and does not even state for which ExtJS version it was intended in the first place.

You will have to search for an equivalent function in the PagingToolbar source code of your version of ExtJS ([6.0.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/src/Paging.js.html#Ext.toolbar.Paging), [6.0.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/Paging.js.html#Ext.toolbar.Paging), [6.0.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/src/Paging.js.html#Ext.toolbar.Paging) or [6.2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Paging.js.html#Ext.toolbar.Paging)), or maybe even write your own (although my gut says that the [`doRefresh`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/Paging.js.html#Ext.toolbar.Paging-method-doRefresh) function could suffice).

I would expect the code sample to exhibit other problems as well, but you can work around that. Once it works as intended, please share the updated code in the comments section below the original source code for future readers, thank you.

Comment: it's resolved, I've changed bbar by store: `combo.on('select', function (combo, record) {
        store.pageSize = parseInt(record.get('id'), 10);
        store.load();
    }, this); `